# Ограничение CREATE TABLE на вставку пустоты в столбец

Tags: sql

При создании столбца указано NOT NULL, но можно вставить значение ''. Как этого избежать?

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[users](
    userId INTEGER IDENTITY(1, 1),
    userName VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

INSERT INTO [dbo].[users] (userId,userName)
VALUES ('ivanov'),('');

SELECT userName 
FROM [dbo].[users];
```

Comment: `CONSTRAINT userName_not_empty CHECK (userName != '')`. Или, возможно, даже `CONSTRAINT userName_not_empty CHECK (LTRIM(userName) != '')`.

Comment: работает, отлично!! спасибо!!!